# Get the calling package/procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm writing a logging procedure in Oracle 10g which writes to a table with the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO EXEC_LOG VALUES (
  (SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSIONID') sessionid FROM dual),
  strPackage, strProcedure, strEventType, strEventLevel, SYSDATE, strMessage
);
```

This procedure is reused in multiple different packages/procedures, but the way it is now, the programmer has to pass their package/procedure name to the logging procedure (`strPackage` and `strProcedure`).

I'm wondering if there is a v$ view or something in Oracle which can tell me what package/procedure this procedure was called from, thus eliminating the need for the programmer to pass in `strPackage` and `strProcedure`.

EXAMPLE:

If I call these two procedures:

```
BEGIN
  log_test.testproc1;
  log_test.testproc2;
END;
```

From this package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY log_test IS
  PROCEDURE TestProc1 IS
    BEGIN
      write_exec_log( ... );    
    END TestProc1;
  PROCEDURE TestProc2 IS
    BEGIN
      write_exec_log( ... );     
    END TestProc2;  
 END log_test;
```

I would want to be able to evaluate `log_test`/`TestProc1` and `log_test`/`TestProc2` from insdie the `write_exec_log` method.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Oracle 12c you can use the built in package UTL_CALL_STACK (http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_call_stack.htm).

Short example if you are just interested in the calling procedure:
`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_Call_Stack.Concatenate_Subprogram(UTL_Call_Stack.Subprogram(2)));`

Or to print the complete call stack:

```
FOR j IN REVERSE 1..UTL_Call_Stack.Dynamic_Depth() LOOP 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_Call_Stack.Concatenate_Subprogram(UTL_Call_Stack.Subprogram(j)));
END LOOP;
```

Example with your package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE  log_test IS
 PROCEDURE write_exec_log(msg VARCHAR2);
 PROCEDURE TestProc1;
 PROCEDURE TestProc2;  
 PROCEDURE TestProc3;
END log_test; 
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY log_test IS
 PROCEDURE write_exec_log(msg VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(msg);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- ');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('calling procedure/function: '
                      ||UTL_Call_Stack.Concatenate_Subprogram(
                                                              UTL_Call_Stack.Subprogram(2)
                                                             )
                       );
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- ');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Call Stack');
   FOR j IN REVERSE 1..UTL_Call_Stack.Dynamic_Depth() LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_Call_Stack.Concatenate_Subprogram(
                                                               UTL_Call_Stack.Subprogram(j)
                                                              )
                        );
   END LOOP;
  END write_exec_log;
 PROCEDURE TestProc1 IS
  BEGIN
   write_exec_log( 'msg TestProc1' );    
  END TestProc1;
 PROCEDURE TestProc2 IS
  BEGIN
   write_exec_log( 'msg TestProc2' );     
  END TestProc2;  
 PROCEDURE TestProc3 IS
  BEGIN
   TestProc2;
  END TestProc3;  
END log_test; 
/

exec log_test.TestProc1
exec log_test.TestProc2
exec log_test.TestProc3
```

(Sorry, no sqlfiddle, no 12c available at the time of writing)

Answer (score 1):

[Tom Kyte's Who_Called_Me should work.](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkytewhocalledme.html)

Comment: This will get me the package name, but not the procedure name.  I added an example to the question.  The call stack contains `log_test` but not `TestProc1`.

Comment: You can get the line number from the package. Is that close enough?

Comment: Not really, I want to use this for performace metrics also, so I'd want to know what procedure is running when the `write_exec_log` is called.

Comment: To do that would require looking at the database dictionary for every call. Performance would nosedive. Also, procedure/function names are ambiguous due to overloading. Perhaps you can get the procedure/function name after-the-fact?

Comment: @AdamHawkes - querying the dictionary might work acceptably fast if you cache the results in some sort of look-aside table, so that only the first call from a particular location pays the dictionary lookup penalty.

Comment: @BobJarvis - You are right, but it is still kinda ugly and seems error-prone to do it that way. What about nested procedures? That's just...wonky.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Qualtagh/OracleDBUtils/blob/master/utl_call_stack.9.sql) is the implementation (a backport) of `utl_call_stack` for Oracle 9. And for Oracle [10 and 11](https://github.com/Qualtagh/OracleDBUtils/blob/master/utl_call_stack.sql).

Another solution (with [p_stack](https://github.com/Qualtagh/OracleDBUtils/blob/master/p_stack.sql) package):

```
dbms_output.put_line( p_stack.getConcatenatedSubprograms( p_stack.whoCalledMe ) );
```

With [GWu's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454722/4540645), it would output:

```
LOG_TEST.TESTPROC1
LOG_TEST.TESTPROC2
LOG_TEST.TESTPROC2
```

Those are only the last calls. Or, if you need full stacks:

```
dbms_output.put_line( p_stack.getCallStack );
dbms_output.put_line( '' );
```

This would output:

```
493: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY P_STACK.FUNCTION GETCALLSTACK.FUNCTION GETCALLSTACK
4: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY LOG_TEST.PROCEDURE WRITE_EXEC_LOG
9: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY LOG_TEST.PROCEDURE TESTPROC1
2: YOUR_SCHEMA.ANONYMOUS BLOCK

493: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY P_STACK.FUNCTION GETCALLSTACK.FUNCTION GETCALLSTACK
4: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY LOG_TEST.PROCEDURE WRITE_EXEC_LOG
13: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY LOG_TEST.PROCEDURE TESTPROC2
3: YOUR_SCHEMA.ANONYMOUS BLOCK

493: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY P_STACK.FUNCTION GETCALLSTACK.FUNCTION GETCALLSTACK
4: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY LOG_TEST.PROCEDURE WRITE_EXEC_LOG
13: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY LOG_TEST.PROCEDURE TESTPROC2
17: YOUR_SCHEMA.PACKAGE BODY LOG_TEST.PROCEDURE TESTPROC3
4: YOUR_SCHEMA.ANONYMOUS BLOCK
```

It works for Oracle versions from 9 to 12.